# Angular app route redirecting to home

Tags: angularjs

In app.js there are a lot of things. But releavant parts are:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home.notfound, {
            url: '/notfound,
            templateUrl: 'modules/main/views/404.html'
        })
        .state('home.unauthorized', {
            url: '/unauth',
            templateUrl: '/unauthorized'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home/main');

.run(function ($rootScope, localize, CookieService, $location) {

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(scope, next) {
  var userCookie = CookieService.getCookie(Config.loginCookie, true);
  if(next.loginRequired){
    if(!userCookie){
      // Logout user without cookie
      $location.path('/login');
    }
  }
  else{
      return;
  }
```

Routes are defined in files like: name.route.js

A route named unit.route.js contains:

```
define([],function(){
function routeConfiger($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('home.unit', {
        url: '/units',
        templateUrl: 'unit.html',
        controller: 'unitCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'unit',
        loginRequired:true
    });
}
routeConfiger.$inject=['$stateProvider'];
return routeConfiger;
});
```

A route named case.route.js contains:

```
define([],function(){
function routeConfiger($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('home.viewCase', {
        url: '/viewcase/:caseId',
        templateUrl: 'case-view.html',
        controller: 'caseViewCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'caseView',
        loginRequired:true
    })
```

Now, when I open a browser and type

```
http://localhost/home/units/
```

then I see the page unit.html.

However, if I type

```
http://localhost/home/viewcase/50/
```

somewhere, a redirect takes over and redirect the page to

```
http://localhost/home/main
```

If from main page, I click on a link which has a ng-click like this:

```
$state.go("home.viewCase", { caseId: '50' });
```

Then a "local" redirect happens and the page goes to

```
case-view.html
```

Im not able to understand what stops going directly to the viewcase:id.

Why does it work for the route "units" but not for the route "case"?

Comment: mmm don't you have a abstract:true routing for .home?

Comment: No. I could not find any reference to "abstract" in the project.

Comment: mmm looks really weird ... what if you try to add in the app.js files something like: $stateProvider
        .state('home, {
            url: '/home, abstract:true,
            templateUrl: 'modules/main/views/common.html'
        })

Comment: Thank you. But could you eplain why this should help? Im still wondering why a certain route works (when going directly to it) but another doesn't. Why would this abstract help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what the issue was.
it actually worked. But not locally. Locally Im using grunt. And for some reason the redirect didnt work. But on other servers, where angular is served by nginx, going directly to a specific route works.